# Whats called first - Object Initializer or Construtor?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I was wondering whats gets called first 
lets say i have this code

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        MyNumber = 6;
    }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and then i call it

```
var o = new MyObject {MyNumber = 8 };
```

What will `MyNumber` be - 6 or 8 ?

And lets say i have set this too

```
public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 7;
```

whats the order? what takes presents?

Comment: This seems simple enough for you to test...

Comment: i am sure it is a duplicate

Comment: Not the right duplicate, may be there is other.

Comment: you might want to read : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/

Comment: if you are using `auto-property initializer` can you please update your tag to be c# 6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your statement:

```
var o = new MyObject {MyNumber = 8 };
```

is equivalent to *somewhat*

```
var o = new MyObject();
o.MyNumber = 8;
```

so the result you will get back is `8`, since any value assigned to `MyNumber` will be overridden due to object initialization.

With property initializer it would be the same result, the only difference is that:

- At the time of constructor call, the property `MyNumber` will have the default value of `7`
- In the constructor it would be assigned `6`
- But due to Object initializer it will be assigned `8`

In case of object intializer it is the constructor that is called first.

[How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

> The **compiler processes object initializers by first accessing the
>   default instance constructor** and then processing the member
>   initializations. Therefore, if the default constructor is declared as
>   private in the class, object initializers that require public access
>   will fail.

Answer (score 3):

> What will MyNumber br 6 or 8 ?

It will be 8. When the following line would be executed:

```
var o = new MyObject {MyNumber = 8 };
```

an object of type `MyObject` would be created and afterwards the value of `MyNumber` would be set to 8. Under the hood the default constructor would be used for the creation of the object. So before `MyNumber` would be set to 8, it would be 6.

> and whats the story with the 7 i just added?

It is the same as for the above case. Now, you are in the case of an auto property initializer (a feature that has been introduced in C# 6). The following

```
public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 7;
```

is equivalent as to initialize the value of `MyNumber` inside the default constructor.

If you create a console application with the following code:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        MyNumber = 6;
    }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new MyObject { MyNumber = 8 };
    }
}
```

and then compile the code and decompile it using ildasm, you will get the following picture, if you look at the IL code of Main.

[image]

From the first underlined line it's clear that the default object initializer is called. Then at the second underline line the value of a 8 is set to the corresponding backing field.

Furthermore, If you compile the code for the following console app:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 8;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new MyObject { MyNumber = 8 };
    }
}
```

you will get exactly the same IL code !

Answer (score -1):

There's one use case not covered by the other answer that is when assigning the new object to a class or struct field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyObject m;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        this.m = new MyObject { MyNumber = 8 };
    }
}
```

Because that field might be in use outside of the class and the statement looks atomic to the user, the compiler generates a temporary variable and only assigns a value to the field when completely initialized:

```
var temp = new MyObject();
temp.MyNumber = 8;
this.m = temp;
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the actual question asked.  If you would like to comment on another answer, then you should post a comment; you should not be posting an answer when not even attempting to answer the quesiton.